# How to allow mesibo on-premise in csf firewall

Tags: centos7, mesibo, csf

I followed this [tutorial](https://mesibo.com/documentation/on-premise/) to run Mesibo On-Premise on my Centos 7 server with csf firewall

But When i try to run it, it keeps resulting:

`onp: Unable to verify app token - network error`

It only works without any errors when csf is disabled or if the ip address: 5.9.22.121 is in csf.allow file

But there wasn't any note about this in the tutorial

**Logs:**

```
E0507-211137-014 (1): starting mesibo
E0507-211137-015 (1): PID: 1
E0507-211137-015 (1): build date: Mon Jun 28 08:59:22 2021 UTC
E0507-211137-015 (1): build number: 3845
E0507-211137-015 (1): module_exports_init
E0507-211137-016 (1): Local IP count: 2
E0507-211137-016 (1): --> multiple(2) IPs found - listening on all the IPs. If you like to use particular IPs only, set them in configuration using one or more 'ip' fields
E0507-211137-044 (1): signal ignored: 17
E0507-211137-045 (1): Local IP Address: x.x.x.x
E0507-211137-045 (1): Local IP Address: 172.17.0.1
E0507-211138-055 (14): Connect Failure - 5.9.22.121:3101 ()
E0507-211138-056 (14): onp: Unable to verify app token - network error
E0507-211150-663 (14): Connect Failure - 5.9.22.121:3101 ()
E0507-211150-664 (14): onp: Unable to verify app token - network error
E0507-211204-231 (14): Connect Failure - 5.9.22.121:3101 ()
E0507-211204-231 (14): onp: Unable to verify app token - network error
E0507-211215-975 (14): Connect Failure - 5.9.22.121:3101 ()
E0507-211215-975 (14): onp: Unable to verify app token - network error
```

So, What am i missing ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you read this? https://mesibo.com/documentation/faq/on-premise/#does-on-premise-requires-internet

> Yes, on-premise requires internet access for authenticating with the
> mesibo server and the billing purpose. You should ensure that the
> on-premise server is able to connect to **onp-auth.mesibo.com**

Comment: Yes, my server has internet
the problem is in the csf firewall

Comment: if the firewall is disabled or if the ip address: 5.9.22.121 is in csf.allow file, mesibo works without any problems

Comment: Read my answer again, it says you should allow it to connect to onp-auth.mesibo.com. if your firewall blocks it, it won't work.